# How to change primary language of an app in iTunesConnect?

Tags: app-store-connect

Apple documentation says that I need to *"choose the new language from the Primary Language menu"*:

[image]

but I see no such a menu (Primary Language menu) after clicking "About This App". I see just an info window, not selectable at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language inside iTunes Connect only refers to the description of it. The default language is set in Xcode before uploading the build. (inside the info.plist)

Comment: alright, did not see the date. thanks for giving me credit anyway :)